# Overriding account controller

Tags: magento, controller, magento-1.7

I try to override function in controller `/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`.

I create module folders:

`/app/code/local/Mandarin/SkipLogoutSuccess/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mandarin_SkipLogoutSuccess>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mandarin_SkipLogoutSuccess>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mandarin_skiplogoutsuccess before="Mage_Customer">Mandarin_SkipLogoutSuccess</mandarin_skiplogoutsuccess>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Mandarin/SkipLogoutSuccess/controllers/AccountController.php

```
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';

class Mandarin_SkipLogoutSuccess_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
    public function logoutAction()
    {
        $this->_getSession()->logout()->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl());
        Mage::log("its Allive!", null, 'mygento.log');
        $this->_redirectUrl(Mage::getUrl());
    }
}
```

/app/etc/modules/Mandarin_SkipLogoutSuccess.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config>
    <modules>
         <Mandarin_SkipLogoutSuccess>
              <active>true</active> 
              <codePool>local</codePool> 
         </Mandarin_SkipLogoutSuccess>
    </modules>
 </config>
```

When I run logoutAction controller is used from core. In my log file I don`t get message.
Where could be the error?

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a copy-paste error:

In your config.xml you reference the namespace "<checkout>" but it should be "<customer>" (and of course the closing tag too)

Answer (score 1):

In your config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <customer> <!-- should be customer -->
```

And in Mandarin_SkipLogoutSuccess.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config>
    <modules>
         <Mandarin_SkipLogoutSuccess>
              <active>true</active> 
              <codePool>local</codePool> 
              <depends>
                  <Mage_Customer /> <!-- Make sure this is loaded first -->
              </depends>
         </Mandarin_SkipLogoutSuccess>
    </modules>
 </config>
```